# Complex assignments with comma separator

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have a serie of string that will be pass to a function, and that function must return an array. The string is a serie of vars to be export on bash, and some of that vars may be a json. This is the possible list of string as example and the expected result:

| string | return | desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ONE=one | `[ "ONE=one" ]` | Array of one element |
| ONE="{}" | `[ 'ONE="{}"' ]` | Array of one element with quoted value. |
| ONE='{}' | `[ "ONE='{}'" ]` | Array of one element with simple quoted value |
| ONE='{attr: \"value\"}' | `[ "ONE='{attr: \\"value\\"}'" ]` | Array of one element |
| ONE='{attr1: \"value\", attr2:\"value attr 2\"}' | `[ "ONE='{attr1: \\"value\\", attr2:\\"value attr 2\\"}'" ]` | Array of one element and json inside with multiples values |
| ONE=one,TWO=two | `[ "ONE=one", "TWO=two" ]` | Array of two elements |
| ONE=one, TWO=two | `[ "ONE=one", "TWO=two" ]` | Array of two elements (Ignoring space after comma) |
| ONE='{}', TWO=two | `[ "ONE='{}', TWO=two" ]` | Array of two elements, one quoted |
| ONE='{}',TWO='{}',THREE='{}' | `[ "ONE='{}'", "TWO='{}'", "THREE='{}'" ]` | Array of three elements |
| ONE='{}', TWO=two, THREE=three | `[ "ONE='{}',", "TWO=two", "THREE=three" ]` | Array of three elements, one quoted |

How can i get the correct regex or process to get the expected result on each one?

This is what i have:

```
    function parseVars(envString) {
        let matches = envArg.matchAll(/([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+=(["']?)((?:\\\2|(?:(?!\2)).)*)(\2))(\,\s?)?/g);
        let ret = [];
        for (const match of matches) {
            ret.push(match[1].trim())
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

And tests:

```
    describe("parseVars function", () => {
        it("should be one simple variable", () => {
            expect(parseVars("ONE=one")).toMatchObject([
                "ONE=one"
            ]);
        });
        it("should be two simple variable", () => {
            expect(parseVars("ONE=one,TWO=two")).toMatchObject([
                "ONE=one",
                "TWO=two"
            ]);
        });
        it("should be two simple variable (Trim space)", () => {
            expect(parseVars("ONE=one, TWO=two")).toMatchObject([
                "ONE=one",
                "TWO=two"
            ]);
        });
        it("should be simple json", () => {
            expect(parseVars("ONE='{}'")).toMatchObject([
                "ONE='{}'",
            ]);
        });
        it("should be three simple json", () => {
            expect(parseVars("ONE='{}',TWO='{}',THREE='{}'")).toMatchObject([
                "ONE='{}'",
                "TWO='{}'",
                "THREE='{}'",
            ]);
        });
        it("should be three simple json (Simple quote)", () => {
            expect(parseVars("ONE='{}'")).toMatchObject([
                "ONE='{}'",
            ]);
        });
        it("should be three simple json with attribute", () => {
            expect(parseVars("ONE='{attr: \"value\"}'")).toMatchObject([
                "ONE='{attr: \"value\"}'",
            ]);
        });
        it("should be complex json with multiple attributes", () => {
            expect(parseVars("ONE='{attr1: \"value\", attr2:\"value attr 2\"}'")).toMatchObject([
                "ONE='{attr1: \"value\", attr2:\"value attr 2\"}'",
            ]);
        });
    
        it("should be one json and one simple var", () => {
            expect(parseVars("ONE='{}', TWO=two")).toMatchObject([
                "ONE='{}'",
                "TWO=two",
            ]);
        });
        it("should be one json and two simple vars", () => {
            expect(parseVars("ONE='{}', TWO=two, THREE=three")).toMatchObject([
                "ONE='{}'",
                "TWO=two",
                "THREE=three",
            ]);
        });
    });
```

And the results:

```
parseVars function
    ✕ should be one simple variable (4ms)
    ✕ should be two simple variable (1ms)
    ✕ should be two simple variable (Trim space)
    ✓ should be simple json (1ms)
    ✓ should be three simple json
    ✓ should be three simple json (Simple quote)
    ✓ should be three simple json with attribute
    ✓ should be complex json with multiple attributes
    ✕ should be one json and one simple var (1ms)
    ✕ should be one json and two simple vars (1ms)
```

Comment: It may be easier to start with several regular expressions, where each is able to detect and solve a row entry in the table you provided. If you go with that approach, you can then collapse similar tests together as commonalities emerge. In the worst case you can concatenate various expressions together.

Comment: `envString.split(/,\s*(?=[A-Z]+=)/)` works for your current test cases but such isn't safe against input like `A=1, B=', C=3'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your regex is you're only testing the quote enclosures like `ONE='{attr: \"value\"}'`, but not allowing `ONE=one`.

> When you use a capture group with an optional match `(['"]?)`, if it doesn't match, the group still captures a zero-width character. When combine it with a negative lookahead `(?!\2)` it fails everything - any character has a zero-width character in front of it.

You just need to combine the quote enclosure test with `|[^,]*`, so it works for both scenarios.

Here's a simplified version of your concept:

```js
/(?=\b[a-z])\w+=(?:(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*\1|[^,]*)/gi
```

- Explanation

```
(?=\b[a-z])\w+                  any word characters, but must start with an alphabetic character
=                               equal sign
(?:                             non-capturing group
    (['"])(?:\\\1|(?!\1).)*\1   a quote enclosure
    |[^,]*                      or any string that not made by comma
)
```

See the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Q199Ec/1/)

```js
const texts = [
    `ONE=one`,
    `ONE="{}"`,
    `ONE='{}'`,
    `ONE='{attr: \"value\"}'`,
    `ONE='{attr1: \"value\", attr2:\"value attr 2\"}'`,
    `ONE=one,TWO=two`,
    `ONE=one, TWO=two`,
    `ONE='{}', TWO=two`,
    `ONE='{}',TWO='{}',THREE='{}'`,
    `ONE='{}', TWO=two, THREE=three`
];

const regex = /(?=\b[a-z])\w+=(?:(['"])(?:\\\1|(?!\1).)*\1|[^,]*)/gi;

texts.forEach(text => {
  console.log(text, '=>', text.match(regex));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also start the match with a char a-z followed by optional word chars. Then match either from an opening till closing `"` or `'`, or match all except a whitespace or comma without using lookarounds or capture groups.

Using a case insensitive match using `/i`

```
\b[a-z]\w*=(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\'[^\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\'\\]*)*\'|[^\s,]+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `[a-z]\w*=` Match a char a-z, optional word chars and `=`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` Match from `"` till `"` not stopping at an escaped one
  - `|` Or
  - `\'[^\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\'\\]*)*\'` Match from `'` till `'` not stopping at an escaped one
  - `|` Or
  - `[^\s,]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitspace char or `,`
- `)` Close non capture group

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/maNpfr/1/)

```js
const regex = /\b[a-z]\w*=(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|\'[^\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\'\\]*)*\'|[^\s,]+)/gi;
[
  `ONE=one`,
  `ONE="{}"`,
  `ONE='{}'`,
  `ONE='{attr: \"value\"}'`,
  `ONE="{attr: \"value\"}"`,
  `ONE='{attr1: \"value\", attr2:\"value attr 2\"}'`,
  `ONE=one,TWO=two`,
  `ONE=one, TWO=two`,
  `ONE='{}', TWO=two`,
  `ONE='{}',TWO='{}',THREE='{}'`,
  `ONE='{}', TWO=two, THREE=three`
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(regex)))
```